# Typescript: Transform object [name: Type] to interface

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

**I want to transform object:**

```
var user = {
  id: Number,
  name: String
}
```

to interface:

```
type User = {
  id: number
  name: string
}
```

Now I trying this:

```
type Transform<T extends { [key: string]: ObjectConstructor }> = {[P in keyof T]: (T)[P]['prototype']}
type User = Cast<typeof user>
```

Please help me

Comment: I don't see any [casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) going on here; are you sure you're using the right terminology?  Your code seems to be a type transformation (operates on a type) and not a cast (operates on a value). Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mq88kN) what you're looking for?  If so I'll write up an answer. If not, please consider modifying the question to elaborate on what you're trying to do and what the use case is.

Comment: @jcalz Yes Thank you. Sorry for the incorrect terminology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to probe `typeof Number` and `typeof String` for what it constructs: for this you'd use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) like `new (...args: any) => any` and not a particular such constructor type like `ObjectConstructor`.  The type `ObjectConstructor` is specifically `typeof Object`, and has all of `Object`'s static methods like `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`, which `typeof Number` and `typeof String` do not.

But even if you fix that it won't give you what you want.  When you treat the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) and [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String) values as constructors and call `new Number()` or `new String()`, the [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) that comes out will be the object types `Number` and `String` and not the primitive types `number` or `string`.  I assume you want those primitive types.

In JavaScript, the constructors for [primitive wrappers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript) also can be used like plain functions (`Number()` or `String()` without `new`) which return primitives instead of objects.  So for the case shown here, I'd probe the [call signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) like `(...args: any) => any)` instead of the construct signatures, and get the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) instead of the instance type:

```
type Transform<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any) => any>> = { 
  [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]> 
};

type User = Transform<typeof user>

/* type User = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/G4QwTgBArgzgppAvBA3gKAhAlgEwFwQByUAtgEYIA0GEAdiCXAQMoAuYWtA5mgL5ppWATwAOcCABUwIWjABmAezAkAPBIhwAHqzi0cMCACU4AYyU4VAazhCFcyZQgAKAHRvwXGARlCAlBEQAPggfQODkFAgAbQAFbFoIa1t7CQBdAmNWKDBaCVE4NVjU4P5hMQgAVXgkSWlZRWUVMrg7aGrAgQB6ACoIZsrqgNQaTFwCWlIKMABuEboGJggYdk4uWd4Ibs6gA)